# Is it possible to have the NFC URL reuse a browser tab?

Tags: nfc

When I tap an NFC tag with url in it, it gives the option to open the link in the browser. If I go tap that tag again or another similar tag, it prompts user to open the url again in another browser tab. If I'd like to present multiple tags this way, the user may end up with several tabs which I'd like to prevent. Is this something that can be done (without requiring an app be installed that would intercept the NFC tags)